# Single Hashmap vs Several Hashmaps: Effect on Performance?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am writing a program where all the **key-pair** inputted data will be stored in `HashMaps`(`HashMap<Integer, List<String>>`).(It is of **read-heavy** type)

I need to decide whether to store this in a **single large** `HashMap`, or to create **several smaller** `HashMaps`.

Either ways, the program will give the same output, but I need to know about best practices (better performance)?

**Which is the better decision in terms of performance?**

**How much will the performance be affected if single HashMap is selected over Multiple HashMaps?**

Program Details:

Total Data Stored is less than **20,000**.
The key is an `integer`.
The value is a `List<String>`.

Usage: 
The first time the `data` is inputted, a `method` works on it and gives `Output`.

And the data is stored to disc so that for next time, the output can be given with direct command.

Comment: This is a bit vague

Comment: What details would you want me to add?

Comment: @fightfought499 if i resolved your question so mark it correct

Comment: What is the use case of your data? Is it read heavy or write heavy? What performance concerns do you have? Memory usage? GC? etc..

Comment: Details: How much data (10 items, 1000000 items)? How is the data organized (one/many type(s) of objects)? How will you use the data (only save to disc, do 10/1000/1000000 lookups)? My guess is that you will not gain any significant performance by using several HashMaps, but it is hard to tell since I don't know anything about the data.

Comment: @Stefan I have added the details for you. Request you to answer.

Comment: I'd say stick to a single map. If you run in to performance issues (I don't think you will), investigate the idea with several maps. Accepting http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization has saved me a lot of work a lot of times.

Comment: @Stefan In general, does running through a **single large HashMap** take more time than running through **several smaller HashMaps**? Request you to suggest.

Comment: No (assuming "Running through" is the same as "calling map.values()"). If you use map.get() a lot and your hash() and equals() methods are heavy, performance could be impacted. But since your keys are Integers, I'd say No.

Comment: I'll turn this discussion into a proper answer...

Comment: That would be very helpful because this information doesn't seem to be available anywhere. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

See, if you want to store your data (ONLY STORE) and has one type of element in it then use ArrayList and push your data all at once.

but if you have key pair value so Use HashMap and push all at once.

in Terms of **performance**, rather than acquiring memory each time for a list/map is not a good solution just push all data at once

also think if you have your data in different sets of hashMap how will you traverse through it?

in every term you will know its not a good solution to put data in small sets of HashMap, because there is no significant need of it.

and storing a value is not much concern, the main concern is traversing through the HashMap to decreasing the timing of traversing you can use key as in range. and traverse through it.

Comment: I think the question is about implementing a two-level map. Indexed by key1 and key2. The ask is whether it is more efficient to use map of map, or to combine the key and store in a single map.

Comment: @Aman Thanks for your answer. My concern is about performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say stick to a single map. If you run in to performance issues (I don't think you will), investigate the idea with several maps. Accepting http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization has saved me a lot of work a lot of times.

Getting all the values using `map.values()`: There should be no significant difference in performance between looping one large or several small maps.

Making lookups using `map.get(xxx)`: There could be a difference in performance if the `hash()` and `equals()` methods for your key class are heavy. But your keys are Integers so (hash and equals *not* heavy) so there should be no problem.